# First Time Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

when you first land on this site you show a first time div tag appear up top (like a toolbar) which sits offering a link to the FAQ page.

Nice touch! Is this done with jQuery or do you have an example of the code?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Which aspect of SO's first-time-div do you mean, the logic that determines whether the user visits for the first time, or the presentation code that shows the yellow bar on the page?

Answer (score 2):

It's just a few simple elements combined. An absolutely positioned div, a JS fade in effect and a close button that sets a cookie (which is checked server side before including that call to the JS function that displays it).

There's nothing complicated about it, and each discrete part is easy enough to find documentation on with Google.

Answer (score 0):

I would assume it uses a mixture of server-side session management and jQuery. The session management knows if you have already visited (it could also use cookies) and the jQuery makes the "animation" happen (it fade into view).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is done (or at least **can** be done) using the jQuery [Impromptu](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/) plugin.